# Error on Edit Post shows 422 (Unprocessable Entity) in Ajax call

Tags: ajax, laravel

I keep getting a 422(Unprocessable Entity) error, how do I fix this?
The below is my code on ajax call, can someone help me on to fix this problem?

```
    $(document).on('click', '.edit-post', function() {

        $('.edit-modal').css('display','block');
        $('.posts-table').css('display','none');


        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var title = $(this).attr('data-title');
        var slug = $(this).attr('data-slug');
        var category = $(this).attr('data-category');
        var featured_image = $(this).attr('data-image');
        var body = $(this).attr('data-body');

        $('#edit-post-form #edit-title').val(title);
        $('#edit-post-form #edit-slug').val(slug);
        $('#edit-post-form #edit-category').val(category);
        //$('#edit-post-form #edit-image').val(featured_image);
        $('#edit-post-form #edit-body').val(body);
        $('#edit-id').val($(this).data('id'));


    });
    //Update New Post
    $("#update-post").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        id = $('#edit-id').val();
        var title = $('#edit-post-form #edit-title').val();
        var slug = $('#edit-post-form #edit-slug').val();
        var category_id = $('#edit-post-form #edit-category').val();
        var featured_image = $('#edit-post-form #edit-image').val();
        var body = $('#edit-post-form #edit-body').val();

        var form = new FormData();
        form.append('title', title);
        form.append('slug', slug);
        form.append('category_id', category_id);
        form.append('featured_image', featured_image);
        form.append('body', body);


        $.ajax({
            type:'PUT',
            url: "/updatepost/" + id,
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('input[name="_token"]').val()
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form,
            success: function(data) {
                    toastr.success('Successfully Updated Post!', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                    $('#'+ id).html("<tr id='" + data.id + "' class='item'><th>" + data.id + "</th><td>" + data.title + "</td><td>" + data.body + "</td><td>" + data.created_at + "</td><td><button class='edit-modal btn btn-info' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-title='" + data.title + "' data-slug='" + data.slug + "' data-category='" + data.category_id + "' data-image='" + data.featured_image + "' data-body='" + data.body + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit</button></td></tr>");
                    $('.edit-modal').css('display','none');
                    $('.posts-table').css('display','block');
                }

        });
    });
```

The data of the post will show in the edit form, but when I try to submit it after editing some fields, 422 Unprocessable entity keeps showing.

Comment: please include the code of your updatepost controller function

Comment: A 422 is most likely a validation error in laravel. You are probably not passing in the correct values to pass your validation.